# Identify SQL Server deadlock on AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, deadlock

Anybody know how to identify SQL Server deadlocks on AWS RDS? I try

```
dbcc traceon(1222,-1)
```

but I don't have the necessary permissions; the AWS monitoring page doesn't have deadlock info.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also struggling with getting the monitoring within AWS to show the deadlocks. However, I can show you how to enable traceflag 1222. [This blog post on SQLTips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5329/setting-sql-server-configuration-options-with-aws-rds-parameter-groups/) covers almost all of what's needed if you want to use Parameter Groups. It covers everything if you're just going to use PowerShell. Enabling it using either of these methods, and you will see the errors in the log.

One additional thing you'll need to do after you create a customized parameter group with 1222 enabled is to associate that group with your database instance. Select the instance and select modify. Scroll down to find the parameters & settings section. Select the group you defined using the instructions above.

I'm going to keep searching for a way to see the deadlocks directly in the monitor page. Implication is they should be there because you can call up the counter. However, I can't get it to generate any values.

UPDATE:
I'm continuing to research this. You can query the system_health Extended Event session. Even though Extended Events are not available within AWS RDS, system_health is still there. This query works:

```
    WITH fxd
AS (SELECT CAST(fx.event_data AS XML) AS Event_Data
    FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'system_health*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL) AS fx )
SELECT dl.deadlockgraph
FROM
(
    SELECT dl.query('.') AS deadlockgraph
    FROM fxd
        CROSS APPLY event_data.nodes('(/event/data/value/deadlock)') AS d(dl)
) AS dl;
```